# What is a phrase to describe asking a question that you’re afraid to know the answer to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m writing a line where a character is very anxious, and asks a person a question, but is sort of afraid to know the answer. I’ve written it as “[Question]?” Character X asked character Y, but I feel that the word “asked” does not convey the fact that the character is really afraid to ask this question, since “asked” just sounds casual. I was thinking of using the phrase *reluctantly asked*, but the character isn’t reluctant to ask (they are not hesitating to ask), just afraid to. What word could I use to convey that?

For extra context, the character is afraid to ask a question because one of the possible answers may cause them a lot of trouble.

Comment: People often preface such a question by saying "I hesitate to ask", but then they ask it. It's an idiom that signals the attitude, it's not literal.

Comment: Perhaps "*anxiously asked*".

Comment: Are you looking for a verb, an adverb, a descriptive phrase, or something else?

Comment: *asked fearfully* works just fine: asked with fear [about the answer].

Comment: @StuartF an adverb or a small descriptive phrass

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the verb [venture](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/venture). Cambridge Dictionary has

> **venture**
> <sub>*verb*</sub>
>
> To venture something is to attempt it when you are likely to be wrong or to be criticized.
> *I wouldn’t venture an opinion about that.*
>
> To say something when it is risky to do this.
> *I was too shy to venture a comment.*

The examples don't show a usage when asking a question, but it might be

> I said "Thank you for the assessment," and ventured "How much will the repairs cost?"

Comment: I’m reluctant to use this word due to the more popular meaning of venture—to embark on some journey. I’m not sure if “venture” would be appropriate when asking a question, since the kind of question I’m interested in can’t be “wrong” or “criticized”. The fear stems from one of the possible answers being bad news.

Answer (score 0):

> "And what if I'm not home by eleven?" she asked **apprehensively**.

> **apprehensive** (adj.)
>
> Viewing the future with anxiety or alarm : feeling or showing fear or
> apprehension about the future
>
> **apprehensively** (adv.)
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apprehensively)

---

> "Anything I can do before I leave?" she asked **apprehensively**,
> afraid she would be asked to work overtime for the third night in a
> row.
> [Clive Cussler; *Treasure*](https://books.google.com/books?id=D0Nv0BgeHHgC&pg=PA264&dq=asked%20apprehensively,%20afraid&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO57aHxtyCAxUQMlkFHXDLD_IQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=asked%20apprehensively%2C%20afraid&f=false) (1989)

> "Which robbery are you talking about?" José asks **apprehensively**,
> fearful it was one he had nothing to do with the other day.
> [Nicholas
> Beeson;  *Riemann Zeta*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OllftJezseAC&pg=PA76&dq=he%20asked%20apprehensively,%20fearing&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw4aOPx9yCAxVqD1kFHYomA7EQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=he%20asked%20apprehensively%2C%20fearing&f=false) (2011)